# LevelDB error after power outage

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, full-node, error, leveldb

After a power outage, starting bitcoind I recieved this errors (circled in the image). Reading online some users suggest to do a reindex and i did it but after 11 hours my node isn't reindex yet... The process is still going on about the file `blk03375.dat`. How many blk*.dat it have to reindex? Is this the right procedure for my error?
[image: errors]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the right procedure, although you could have tried a `reindex-chainstate` first since the corruption looks related to the chainstate. It is faster since it only rebuilds the UTxOs index, without the blocks index.

It's to be expected that the reindex takes in the order of hours or days depending on your machine. The number of `blk*****.dat` varies, but after 11 hours and being at the `3375`th `blk` file you are probably close to completion. A more accurate way of tracking the progress would be to look at the `debug.log`'s `UpdateTip` messages.